# Killing process by its command name

Tags: python, bash

I've set of processes with name `process_name` which is substring of execution.

I'm using following command to kill the process. I want to do this natively in python is there any way to do it without using `subprocess.run()` or installing any other dependency.

Command I'm using

```sh
pkill -f  'process_name'
```

System: `18.04`

Comment: Why are you not using `pkill` directly? Why are you showing Bash code if you want to do it from Python? You would need to obtain the PID somehow; how to do that is system-dependent, so you really need to specify on which OS you want to do this.

Comment: @tripleee ohh yea.. I thought I was missing something. pkill -f  'process_name' should do it. But what's the good way to do it in python. And I'm using ubuntu 18.04